# Sprites stuck to border of window when velocity less than 1

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make moving clouds for my game but sprites of clouds stuck to borders when I set the velocity of cloud less than 1. I want that cloud continues moving if a part of the cloud is already outside of the screen.
I found out that sprites stuck if x of rect equals 0. How to fix it?

My code:

```py
class Cloud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cloud, self).__init__()
        images = [load_image(f"cloud{i}.png") for i in range(1, 5)]
        self.image = random.choice(images)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.w)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - self.rect.h)

        self.vel = 10 / FPS  # It returns value less then 1

    def update(self, event=None):
        if not event:
            self.rect.x -= self.vel
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the new position of the object is set to the *Rect* object:

> ```py
> self.rect.x -= self.vel
> ```

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.topleft`) of the rectangle:

```py
class Cloud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cloud, self).__init__()
        images = [load_image(f"cloud{i}.png") for i in range(1, 5)]
        self.image = random.choice(images)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.w)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - self.rect.h)
        self.x, self.y = self.rect.topleft

        self.vel = 10 / FPS  # It returns value less then 1

    def update(self, event=None):
        if not event:
            self.x -= self.vel
            self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```